# How gradient is computed for tf.identity

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, tensor

I found [tf.identity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity?version=stable) is a good way to create a new tensor with the same shape and contents as input. 
It is, however, not clear to me whether gradients can flow over this operation? Is it differentiable operation? Could anyone elaborate more on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The gradient op for an `Identity` op is an identity function. In other words, during backpropagation, the incoming gradient value `dy` is returned as is by the gradient function of an `Identity` op.